# Using MozMill for testing standalone XUL applications

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, tdd, xul, mozmill

As a follow-up of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6797631/287976), I am trying MozMill for testing standalone XUL applications (not a firefox extension). However, I did not "get it" yet - more specifically, how to test a XULRunner-based application.

Consider [this app](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=explorer&chrome=true&srcid=0Bw9sT8pzNEH7YmY4Njg1Y2EtZTIyYS00NjA2LThlOTctYjU2OThlZjIzZDBl&hl=pt_BR), for example. For now, I can run it from command line, more or less this way:

```
$ /path/to/xulrunner /full/path/to/mozmillexample/application.ini
```

I would like to write Mozmill scripts to test it. For example, I would like to write a test such as this one, which has as "taste" of unit testing:

```
 Components.utils.import("chrome://mozmillexample/content/example.js", example);
 var setupModule = function(module) {
     module.controller = mozmill.getBrowserController(); // Or what?
 }

var testEquals = function() {
    jumlib.assertEqual(example.exHello(), "Hello, World!", "Should be equal");
}
```

I would like to write some functional tests, too:

```
 Components.utils.import("chrome://mozmillexample/content/example.js", example);
 var setupModule = function(module) {
     module.controller = mozmill.getBrowserController(); // Or what?
 }

var testAlerts = function() {
    var button = findElement.Elem(document.getElementById('button'));
    button.click();
    controller.window.assertAlert(); // I bet it does not exist but it gives the idea...
}
```

Unfortunately, however, I did not find any documentation about testing standalone apps, at least none explaining the basic steps. So I ask: is it possible to write tests like these ones? How could I do it, if it is possible?

Answer (score 3):

I got it to work with the MozMill extension; unpack the extension and edit the following files:

- add this to install.rdf at the right place:

  ```
  <em:targetApplication>
    <Description>
      <em:id>mozmill@example.com</em:id>
      <em:minVersion>0.9</em:minVersion>
      <em:maxVersion>1.1</em:maxVersion>
    </Description>
  </em:targetApplication>`
  ```
- create a folder "extensions" in the application's root (where application.ini and the "chrome" and the "defaults" folder are); paste the unpacked mozmill extension there.
- Enable the extension manager as described in [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XULRunner_tips#Extension_Manager)
- embed the MozMill Extension code in your XULRunner app: `<script src="chrome://mozmill/content/overlay.js"/>`
- Enable the extension by adding or modifying `%appdata%\Adam Brandizzi\MozMill Example\Profiles\123455.default\extensions.ini:
  [ExtensionDirs]
  Extension0=C:\Users\John\Desktop\myXULApp\extensions\mozmill`

  - Use the following JS code to open MozMill: `MozMill.onMenuItemCommand(event);`